# Restricting access to internal WCF services

Tags: wcf, security

We have a couple of WCF services hosted in an asp.net application on IIS. We are getting more and more services used for internal communication(between our own systems, where the client can be located on the same server or on other servers). Now we need to secure these services by some means.

**In short: The purpose is to stop other people from calling our services. Only applications under our control should be able to communicate with these services**

Our current thought:
We already have SSL enabled and we have a public cert for the server. Our current plan is to enable to security by using: clientCredentialType="UserName" where we have a custom validator that simply checks against a username/password we have defined(much like an API key).

Question #1: Is there any better way? The scenario sound simple and I feel we are missing some obvious solution.

Question #2: If we do it this way will the SSL cert we already have be enough or must we create any other certs?

Some context: .net 4, IIS 7, We have access to the server. The clients/services might be located on different servers.

**Update 1:** The client might be located on a completly different network. We have some other systems hosted elsewhere that also need to be able to call these services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand your scenario you have all your servers / services in your network / windows domain, don't you? In such case I would not use `UserName` authentication. Stick with windows security and HTTPS.

To restrict access to your service you have several options all based on Windows accounts used to run you allowed clients for your internal services. Assign these client accounts to domain group and after that you can:

- User standard .NET Role based security `PrincipalPermission` or `PrincipalPermissionAttribute`. This has disadvantage that you must hardcode authorization to your services. Only users from defined windows group will be able to access the service
- The former approach can be hopefully (untested with WCF but works greatly with ASP.NET) with ASP.NET role provider. In such case you can use custom non windows role in permissions and use `AutorizationStoreRoleProvider` (AzMan) to map domain users or domain groups to your custom role. Again it demands hardcoding at least permissions for custom roles.
  [How to use Authorization manager with ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649313.aspx)
  [How to use ASP.NET Role provider in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702542.aspx)
- Create custom `ServiceAuthorizationManager` where you will use claims for windows role to authorize the user. The advantage of this approach is that you can add authorization manager through configuration so you don't have to touch any code of your services. 
  [How to create custom AuthorizationManager for WCF service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731774.aspx)

Comment: +1 For a good answer. Unfortunately I was a bit unclear in my question. Some of the clients might be located on other networks. Maybe I sholdn't have called it "internal" but I couldn't find a better word. I updated the question with this information.

Comment: In such case `UserName` is necessary and you can still combine it with custom authorization manager or with role provider.

Comment: Even client on other network can authenticate with windows account but you will have to use basic authentication.

Comment: Sorry I have been away for a while and haven't had time to test it. I couldn't enable windows auth in IIS for this project so userName would have been best for us I think. We decided to use another solution though which requires manual checking of the credentials. But thnx for a good answer.